# Looking for a Delphi Gantt chart component

Tags: delphi, components, gantt-chart

Does anyone have any experience with using a Gantt chart control in Delphi?  I'm looking for a native VCL one but ActiveX would also do.

I don't have too many requiremetnts other than it looking half decent and has very basic editing.

thanks for any suggestions

Edit: I am on Delphi 2009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up going with Gantt-Grid from Exontrol

http://www.exontrol.com/exg2antt.jsp

Really good looking, lots of functionality and great support.

If your using it with Delphi watch out for this http://www.exontrol.com/sg.jsp?content=support/faq/delphi/#fpu

Comment: Hi Jamie, I also use the G2antt.  The support is very good although I do find the control a bit quirky at times.  I'm using the COM version in a MS Access Project (SQL Server database). Hopefully we will see a few more Exontrol users on StackOverflow in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have a long history of use with PlexityHide. Reliable, good and extended documentation, good support. EzPlan-IT is another good Gant with good suport from author. Its in the landscape since many years. A bit less functions then PlexityHide, a bit easier to use.

Comment: I have used this component in one application. It has a fairly steep learning curve, but is very flexible. The default look for scroll bars etc was a bit dated, but owner draw options allowed using ThemeServices.  There seems to be a D2009 version.

Answer (score 0):

The TeeChart that comes with Delphi has Gantt support. You can see it in the provided demo. WHere to find that demo varies with the version of Delphi you have installed.

For Delphi 7 and earlier, you can find it in your ($DELPHIDIR)\Demos\TeeChart folder. In Delphi 2007/9 on WinXP, it's in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Shared Documents\RAD Studio\x.0\Demos.

EDIT: For D2009/2010, you can download demos from the [TeeChart website](http://www.steema.com/downloads/dwn_tch_vcl.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at http://www.gantt-component.com/index.htm or http://plexityhide.com/gtp.htm. Can't comment on the component's quality though.

Answer (score 0):

EZPlan-It from A-Dato is very pricy, sometimes ago i found [GantChart](http://www.dancemammal.com/ganttchart.htm) component, i don't know how stable it is but perhaps you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I found this just today: https://www.gantt-component.com

It's VCL. From the screenshots it seems to be quit feature-rich!